# Unable to add CardView to layout in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-cardview

I am using Eclipse and trying to add `CardView` to my layout. However I keep getting an exception:

```
02-27 23:33:41.982: E/AndroidRuntime(20071): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-27 23:33:41.982: E/AndroidRuntime(20071): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.materialcontactpicker/com.example.materialcontactpicker.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.CardView

... most of the crap that you usually ignore ...

02-27 23:33:41.982: E/AndroidRuntime(20071): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.cardview.R$styleable
02-27 23:33:41.982: E/AndroidRuntime(20071):    at android.support.v7.widget.CardView.initialize(CardView.java:203)
02-27 23:33:41.982: E/AndroidRuntime(20071):    at android.support.v7.widget.CardView.<init>(CardView.java:101)
02-27 23:33:41.982: E/AndroidRuntime(20071):    ... 24 more
```

I have:
1. Imported `appcompat_v7` to my workspace, added it to libraries.
2. Imported `cardview` project and added it to libraries.
3. Configured the build path and added `cardview` to the "Projects".
4. My `targetSdkVersion` is 21.

However, I still get the error.

**How do I solve this?**

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue yesterday in eclipse. Below steps work for me.

1. Remove cardView project from buildpath. Delete existing CardView project from workspace.
2. Clean Project.
3. Restart eclipse.
4. Import CardView project again.
5. Right click on the CardView Project. Go to Properties. Make sure "is Library" option is checked.
6. Now right click on your project -> build path -> configure build path -> Under projects tab, add cardview.

Hope it helps..